# KQL query, how to extend information from rendereddescription

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I want to extend the query result with specific values, but I do not know how to get only a fragment of information, the one that is in the screen, that is, for example, from the "rendereddescription" section, I only need information about "server_principal_name" and assign it to some value, e.g. "user" and this I know this needs to be resolved | extend "variable name" = i here i do not know what the syntax is.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4DZ9.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `parse` operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator

for example:

```
print RenderDescription = @"... 0000000000 session_server_principal_name:ABB\HPAM-TCS-DB10 server_principal_sid:01050000000 ...."
| parse RenderDescription with * "session_server_principal_name:" session_server_principal_name " " *
```

| RenderDescription | session_server_principal_name |
| --- | --- |
| ... 0000000000 session_server_principal_name:ABB\HPAM-TCS-DB10 server_principal_sid:01050000000 .... | ABB\HPAM-TCS-DB10 |

Comment: Hello Yoni,
Can we contact somehow? i have a problem with KQL Query and i'm not able to handle this by myself or post it on stackoverflow because problem is hard to describe via chat.